# WinAPI check if a window has a regular title bar

Tags: c++, winapi, titlebar

I want my program to reliably determine if a window (given its handle) has a regular windows style title bar (like windows explorer, control panel and most of the desktop apps) or a custom one (google chrome, visual studio, spotify, store apps).

Is there a specific flag in `GWL_STYLE` or `GWL_EXSTYLE`, or is there an other way to check the title bar style?

Comment: There is the WS_CAPTION flag that is part of the windows style bits (backed by GWL_STYLE)), but that will not tell you whether a window performs custom non-client operations. I doubt there is any way to reliably know that a window has a purely standard title bar (however it's easy to know one does not).

Comment: Yes, for example, Visual Studio 2017 has the `WS_CAPTION` flag set, and it still looks different from other windows.

Comment: Probably not going to be easy. No styles would indicate this. Read the source code of a program that has such a caption bar to find out how they do it

Comment: What do you need this information for? Smells like a XY problem to me.

Comment: I want to make a program that re-skins all the standard windows. I have a very specific reason why I can't use programs like WindowBlinds by Stardock, and I am trying to come up with my own solution. So far what i've come up with is to create a skinned in WPF window and host the target window in it. Obviously, this would only apply to windows with no custom title bars. I'm sure there is a way better solution, like injecting a DLL into the target process and having it handle `WM_NCPAINT` or something like that, but I haven't been able to get that working.

Comment: Maybe that would be worth a separate question thread, but knowing how SO works, I'm too afraid to ask, because it would certainly get tons of downvotes and it would only ruin my reputation score.

Comment: Would you consider a program, that paints its own title bar that looks exactly like Windows' one, a regular one? If yes, the only way you will be able to do it is reading the pixels out of the other window and implementing a way to determine if they indeed look like one ;-)

Comment: @LázárZsolt I don't think injecting a DLL into the other project is a good idea, to be honest: you may crash the other process, or worse, some antivirus or DRM system may flag you (and even worse, a user may get banned in some platform for it).

Comment: @Acorn Then how does WindowBlinds not get flagged by antiviruses? From what I understood, it injects a DLL into all running processes and overrides `WM_NCPAINT`.

Comment: @LázárZsolt No idea. Either it is white-listed, or antiviruses do not flag that; I don't really know. However, at least DRM and anti-cheat systems do indeed look for such kind of thing.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to define what you consider "regular" and, therefore, what is "custom".

For instance, typical applications will have `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_BORDER` set, if I recall correctly. If you consider that "normal", then it is easy to consider everything else custom and you are done.

To decide on your criteria, I suggest you inspect the applications you mention and others, and finally decide what is the set of conditions you need.

Further information:

- [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles)
- [Extended Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles)
- [Window Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#window-types)

Comment: The styles don't tell you anything because the program paints its own non client area and so the styles are ignored.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed. Although it is the only approximation you can get without going into debugging the other process or doing hacks like trying to read the pixels of the title bar and see if they follow the standard style.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work at all so it's totally useless. Also, the user said, "I don't know which style to check", and you answered, "try to work out which styles to check".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not sure what you mean. It does work to already filter out many programs already. Then, for those that aren't filtered, maybe you can use a black-list that you keep updated, possibly by users. It all depends on what OP is trying to do. But this should be the first filter, the way I see it.